# kafkacat for event hub

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, azure-eventhub

hi I tried to check connection to eventhub using kafkacat in one of my VM in azure
I gave the following parametrs(fill my hab name and all):

```
 kafkacat \
-b <your-hub-name>.servicebus.windows.net:9092 \
-X security.protocol=sasl_ssl \
-X sasl.mechanism=PLAIN \
-X sasl.username='$ConnectionString' \
-X sasl.password='Endpoint=sb://<your-hub-name>.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=<primary-key>' \
-L
```

but I keep getting:
% ERROR: Failed to acquire metadata: Local: Broker transport failure

what can go wrong here ? do I have to create a topic and SAS authentication and take his keys?

Comment: for -b, you should use [event hub namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-create#create-an-event-hubs-namespace), not [event hub instance name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-create#create-an-event-hub). and for sasl.password, you should follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-get-connection-string#get-connection-string-from-the-portal).

Comment: stil not working , I must have an instance for that ? or it probably network issue?

Comment: Please add an eventhub instance.

Comment: created  should I create a SAS key for it and use this one for connection?, thank you for the help!

Comment: no, you can use the default sas connection string.

Comment: I tried this but it didnt worked still same error any suggestion why?

Answer (score 3):

The port of eventhub with kafka protocol is 9093.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-kafka-connect-tutorial

```
bootstrap.servers={YOUR.EVENTHUBS.FQDN}:9093 # e.g. namespace.servicebus.windows.net:9093
```